# How do you manually insert a uuid type field in Postgres SQL DB?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table with a field called `user_uuid` with type `uuid`.  I also have a valid UUID value that I want to manually insert in that row, but I can't seem to find a way to manually create this.

This is an example of the statement I'm trying to execute:

```
insert into my_table (account_number, type,  user_uuid) values ('1252', 'residential', 'dOfa6513-aOfd-4e78-9941-724b22804e9f');
```

I've tried appending `::UUID` which I read somewhere might work, and to enclose the UUID text value inside curly brackets, instead of single quotes. None of that has worked, and the docs are not helpful either.  The error I get is the following:

```
 invalid input syntax for type uuid: 'dOfa6513-aOfd-4e78-9941-724b22804e9f'
```

Comment: UUID is in hexadecimal, that's base-16, and so uses the values `0-9A-F`, and doesn't use the alphabetical character `O`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 occurrences of the letter O in your uuid.
It should have been the digit 0 instead (zero) to make it a proper hexadecimal string: `d0fa6513-a0fd-4e78-9941-724b22804e9f`

Answer (score 4):

The UUID you're trying to insert is not a valid UUID.

You can check the validity here https://www.freecodeformat.com/validate-uuid-guid.php

This is one example of a valid UUID: `a8adfa00-6680-49b3-bf94-caa8c3f1d823`,
can try pass this into your insert query and check if ok.